# Adding UIButton to UItableview cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

i have a grouped tableview which contains 3 sections,i want to add different buttons for each section,,i have 5 cells in the first section,and i want to add only 3 unbuttons in the 2nd ,3r an 4th cell.my code look like this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == 0)
        return [_arayfirstrow count];
    else if(section == 1)
        return [_arraysecondrow count];
    else  if(section == 2)
        return [_arraythirdrow count];
}
   // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   // static NSUInteger nTag = 100;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia"size:20.0];



    }

    // Set up the cell...
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
            cell.textLabel.text = [_arayfirstrow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *imageName = [_arayfirstrowimg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

**//when i add below code for inserting button on the first section ,it successfully adds the button,but i don't need button for 1st and 5th cell..ans also it crashes when i tap the button for 2 or three time**

  CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(210, 25, 65, 25);
     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = buttonRect;
        // set the button title here if it will always be the same
        [button setTitle:@"Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.tag = 1;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.contentView insertSubview:button atIndex:0];



       // [usernamebutton release];

    }else if(indexPath.section == 1){
        cell.textLabel.text = [_arraysecondrow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if(indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [_arraythirdrow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    return cell;
}
```

is there any solution to solve this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: if you scroll you might get something different .,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if(indexPath.row == 1||indexPath.row == 2||indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(210, 25, 65, 25);
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = buttonRect;
        // set the button title here if it will always be the same
        [button setTitle:@"Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.tag = 1;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubView:button atIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Have you defined the method `myAction:`? If not, it might be crashing your application.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is very easy:

Add a Subclass of UITableViewCell to your Project, insert your header and add the cell in your delegate method like so:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SpecialCell";
// static NSUInteger nTag = 100;
YourTableViewCellClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (specialCell == nil) {
    specialCell = [[[YourTableViewCellClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

In your new own Cell class add your buttons and views as you like with

```
[self addSubview:button];
```

This is your special cell, the cell for your 2nd, 3rd and 4th cell in first section.

Like you already do, init a standard cell the same way as above. 
Now here comes the magic:

```
if(indexPath.section == 0){
    if(indexPath.row == 1||indexPath.row == 2||indexPath.row == 3){
        //add text to buttons of your specialCell
        //add color...
        return specialCell;
    } else {
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Just a small overview, how it is meant to be done.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if(indexPath.row == 1||indexPath.row == 2||indexPath.row == 3)
    {    

UIButton *deletebtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [deletebtn setFrame:CGRectMake(170,5, 25, 25)];
            deletebtn.tag=indexPath.row;
            [deletebtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"log_delete_touch.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [deletebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(DeleteRow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell addSubview:deletebtn];
}
}
```