# UIButton does not work when it in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

My structure of views:

```
UITableView
  UITableViewCell
    UIScrollView
      CustomView
        UIButton
```

The problem is UIButton doesn't work when I touch it.
I create it with code:

```
btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[btn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(tileTouchUpInside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.layer.zPosition = 1;
[self addSubview:btn];
```

I've also add this:

```
scroll.delaysContentTouches = NO;
scroll.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
```

But my button doesn't work anyway. I can't cancelContentTouches or set delay for UITableView because if I set it, UITableView stop scrolling verticaly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you implemented `tileTouchUpInside` method?

Comment: Is userInteractionEnabled YES for CustomView?

Comment: @Capt.Hook - thanks, I've tried, didn't help.
Also, want to add - when I just add CustomView to ViewController, withour scroll, it works perfectly. It stops work if placed in scrollview.

Comment: Check this question: [Allow UIScrollView and its subviews to both respond to a touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485100/allow-uiscrollview-and-its-subviews-to-both-respond-to-a-touch)

Comment: @Capt.Hook thanks, your link helps me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a subclass of UIScrollview with

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
  return NO;
}
```

If you are not getting that message, set:

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

The problem is because of the way `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` behaves by default, it returns NO only if the subview is an UIControl, but your button is hidden inside the CustomView which isn't.

Comment: You can also switch off "Delays content touches" option in IB. This did the trick for me.

Comment: The scroll view stopped scrolling

Comment: It's also worth double checking that the UIScrollView is not in a parent view that is smaller than expected, use  parentView.clipsToBounds = true; to check

Answer (score 4):

Came across the same scenario. UIScrollView in separate class and adding button through a custom view. 'NSNotificationCenter' helped me solving the issue.
Sample code:

```
-(void)tileTouchUpInside:(id)sender
{    
    NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"index" forKey:@"index"];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"Action" object:nil userInfo:dict];
}
```

In the class containing Scroll View:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doAction:) name:@"Action" object:nil];
}
-(void)doAction:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSString* value =[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"index"];
    // .......
}
```

Enable userInteraction for scroll view, custom view and button.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to set the button frame. By default if you use `btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];` method to initialize button it will be `UIButtonTypeCustom`. Also set a background color to it for debugging purpose to note down where the button is actually placed.
 Now for your case you need to set the frame for that button like `btn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);`

For the inner UIScrollView implement this delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
  {
       return ![view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]];
  }
```

This may work.

Comment: Thanks, I set the button frame, just didn't tell about this in code.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers worked for me, because my problem was that the button was not visible at layout time or something...

FIX:

1) move the button out of the `scrollView` completely (to be subview of VC's main `view`).

[image: main view's hierarchy]

2) select the `button` and the element from your `contentV` you want your button located (in my case: after the last element in conventV)

[image: button and last element selection]

3) add the necessary constraints (in my case: to be bottom aligned)

[image]

4) Add the rest of the constraints for the `button`.

5) Enjoy.

Comment: thanks a lot! my solution is similar, i just had to add the autolayout constraints accordingly. tried many ways, using tap gestures, bringing view to front. nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

Your CustomView's frame could be interfering with your UIButton. Are they overlapping? Add your button to the CustomView just to test by `[CustomView addSubview:UIButton];` (using your values of course). If it works, then your issue is most likely an overlap.

Comment: Thanks for idea. But when I just add my CustomView to ViewController, withour scroll, it works perfectly. It stops work if placed in scrollview.

Comment: If you are looking to just add a button for a tableview, take a look at this previous post...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229597/adding-uibutton-to-uitableview-cells

Answer (score 1):

Add all subviews from CustomView to ScrollView. And hide the CustomView. Make sure CustomView(ContainerView of scrollView) should also be a subView of scrollView.

Answer (score 1):

Button does not work in scroll view. I did spend lot of time struggling with this and looking for help. Finally I found this answer:
[Add buttons to UIScrollView Swift 5 programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68579741/17552218)
where UIStackView made things easy.

My adaptation of the solution did go something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let subView = UIView()
    view.addSubview(subView)
    subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        subView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
        subView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
        subView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400),
        subView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),
    ])
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    subView.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
    ])
    
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
    ])
    
    // Create what ever content you need to be shown in the scroll view.
    // In this example long view with a button somewhere in the middle.
    let content = UIView()
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(content)
    content.backgroundColor = .gray
    content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.widthAnchor, constant: -10),
        content.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1000.0),
    ])
    
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
    button.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 400)
    content.addSubview(button)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click), for: .touchDown)
}

@objc func click(_ sender : UIButton) {
    print("Click")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Link from Capt.Hook helped me. I used UIGestureRecognizer instead of UIButtons.

[Allow UIScrollView and its subviews to both respond to a touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485100/allow-uiscrollview-and-its-subviews-to-both-respond-to-a-touch?lq=1)
Use it, if you have the similar problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue & same hierarchy of the views, With latest sdk , just use it :

Setting delaysContentTouches to NO for UIButton in the same UITableViewCell.

```
self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO
```