# UIScrollView with child UIView (holds content) not detecting taps

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm hitting a wall.  I have a UIScrollView with a child UIView (contentView) which contains the content and a button.  The button is not detecting any taps.  I've tested many methods, creating the button programmatically, using storyboard, and creating a UITapGestureRecognizer in the contentView... still nothing.  From what I understand, UIScrollView does not delegate any touch events to it's children.  How do I solve this?

Comment: Have ever try to put your `UIScrollView` inside a `UIView`? The hierarchy should be: `ViewController -> UIView -> UIScrollView -> UIView -> UIButton`.

Comment: @Breek If I'm not mistaken, a UIViewController has an embedded view by default, as when you're adding a UIScrollView programmatically:  view.addSubview(scrollView)... Regardless, I programmatically added a parent UIView to my UIScrollView and still the contentView is not receiving tap events.

Comment: Could you add some code about how you create your button programmatically so we can see the problem you have :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIButton does not work when it in UIScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649639/uibutton-does-not-work-when-it-in-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 1):

You can create the button programmatically then you add it as a subview for your contentView.

```
let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRectMake(contentView.center.x-20.0, contentView.center.y-20.0, 40.0, 40.0)
button.addTarget(self, action: "handleTap", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
button.setTitle("Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

contentView.addSubview(button)
```

On the action you can handle the tap

```
func handleTap() {
    //Do whatever you want
    print("Button tapped")
}
```

I tested it using a scrollView and a UIView inside the scrollView