# SWIFT: in uiscrollview can't press button

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, uitextview

I use uiscrollview and when I click button in scrollview I add text in textView and then button outside view so... when button outside view I scroll down and can't click the button. My code:

change scrollView height:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 1000);
```

[image]

Comment: check autoresizing for all view inside Scrollview. your button is visible but in actual it is not. And also make sure your button have User interaction YES . for checking your Button is visible or not .see my ans below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIButton does not work when it in UIScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649639/uibutton-does-not-work-when-it-in-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the `delaysContentTouches` to `false` on your UIScrollView.

[UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/delaysContentTouches)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, when button is into a subview -> into a ScrollView, the tap will not be cached, non matter what scroll view settings you have..

So I added the button as subview of my scrollView and tap was fired

```
scrollView.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: Although it's against the guidelines of this website, I have to thank you. Your warning about having the button inside a view that's inside the scrollview not working is what _fixed_ my problem. Always thought that the scrollview should only have one subview, but I may have inherited that habit from Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect frameforMainView = mainView.frame;
frameforMainView.size.height = viewFirstAnswerButton.frame.origin.y + viewFirstAnswerButton.frame.size.height;
mainView.frame = frameforMainView;

//Now Set ContentSize Of scroll view;
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, mainView.frame.origin.y + mainView.frame.size.height)];
```

if you are using Autolayouts then don't forget to add `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`

Answer (score 0):

Drag all subviews from mainView to ScrollView. And hide the mainView. Make sure mainView(ContainerView of scrollView) should also be a subView of scrollView.